# Reload bootstrap modal content delay issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've made a modal that is used to load some ajax provided content from the WordPress REST API. 
I need to clean the content when it's closed, this because I'm using the same code to load different contents from different posts type of the website.
I've noticed that if I click on a different link to open the modal and the content is fetched using ajax, it will have a little bit of delay in the update of the content, this will cause that the user will see the previous content that was appended to the modal body. Is there a fix that I can apply to prevent this beahviour?
Here is the code I'm using:

```
const modal = $('#content-modal');
  const modalBody = $('.modal-body');
  const modalTitle = $('.modal-title');

  $('.service').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var type = $(this).attr('data-type');
    $.getJSON('https://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/'+type+'/'+id, function(data){
      modalTitle.html(data.title.rendered);
      modalBody.html(data.content.rendered);
    });
  });

  $('.staff').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var type = $(this).attr('data-type');
    $.getJSON('https://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/'+type+'/'+id, function(data){
      modalTitle.html(data.title.rendered);
      modalBody.html(data.content.rendered);
    });
  });

  modal.on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).modal('dispose');
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case is better if you clean the content in the event "show.bs.modal". with this the form will be clean before to load, for example:

```
const modal = $('#content-modal');
const modalBody = $('.modal-body');
const modalTitle = $('.modal-title');

$('.service').on('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
   var type = $(this).attr('data-type');
   $.getJSON('https://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/'+type+'/'+id, function(data){
      modalTitle.html(data.title.rendered);
      modalBody.html(data.content.rendered);
    });
  });

  $('.staff').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var type = $(this).attr('data-type');
    $.getJSON('https://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/'+type+'/'+id, function(data){
      modalTitle.html(data.title.rendered);
      modalBody.html(data.content.rendered);
    });
  });

  modal.on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).modal('dispose');
  });
```

// just add this //

```
  modal.on('show.bs.modal', function(e){
    modalTitle.html("");
    modalBody.html("");
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've followed your tip, but I wasn't able to understand why the dispose event of bootstrap was not firing to empty the modal content, so I've applied to the `hidden.bs.modal` your suggestion about the modalBody and modalTitle and now all working like a charm.

Comment: Why is there a delay in the first place? I'm also sitting with this issue. Clearing the content works, but there is still a weird jittery behaviour when the modal is shown